# How to test my UI for RLT screen?

Tags: android

I make UI for Android and I want to test it on RLT.
I'm using `ConstraintLayout`.

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your language to any RLT language on your test device to view your layouts in RLT